# How to create matrix or 2d list from lists in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have 3 lists

```
> a= ones((10,1))
> 
> 
>  x_1=[1,2,3,4...,10] (i.e. list of 10 elements)
> 
>  y_1=[2,1,4,7,2,..20] (list of 10 elements)
```

I want to join these 3 list and make it as 2d list or matrix
as:

```
> mat=[a x_1 y_1]
```

like in MATLAB where 
a will be 1 column 
x_1 second column and 
y_1 third column.

```
> mat= [[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,3,4],[]......[]]
```

I tried

```
> np.matrix([[a,[[i] for i in x_1],[[i] for i in y_1]]])
```

but it gave an error as matrix must be 2 dimensionl

How can I do this ?

Also, if I have 2D arrays
i.e.

```
>  a=np.ones((3,2))
> 
> x_1=[[1,2],[2,3],[2,4]]
> 
> y_1=[[3,4],[5,6],[3,4]]
```

Then how can I concatenate these arrays and make it as

```
> c=[[1,1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5,6],[1,2,4,3,4]]
```

In matlab it is written as:

```
> c=[a,x_1,y_1]
```

How can I do this as well?

Comment: Could you please clarify if `a` is a 2D python array.

Comment: Yes a is 2d python array. Sorry I missed np before ones. I have updated it now. So a is [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay within "standard" Python (no `numpy`), then to get a transposed 2D list you could do the following:

```
mat = [p for p in zip(a, x_1, y_1)]
```

If you need a `numpy` array anyway, then:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([a, x_1, y_1]).T
```

NOTE: in the above example replace `np.array` with `np.matrix` if that is what you want.

If your `a` array is a 2D array such as, e.g., `np.ones((10,1))` or `np.ones((10,3))` then you can use one of the *stack() functions in `numpy`:

```
mat = np.vstack([np.asarray(a).T, x_1, y_1]).T
```

Comment: Your solution is great, but it is not working with 3 lists. i.e. I have a=ones((10,1)) too and when I am doing   c=[a,x_1,y_1] it gives an error as "could not broadcast input array from shape (10,1) into shape (10)"

Comment: Actually it works, sorry I was using it wrong. I used a=[1]*10 instead of np.ones((10,1)), then it worked.  Thanx a lot.

Comment: @Eyshika If `a = np.ones((10, 1))` then you can either change the way it is defined, i.e., `a = np.ones(10)` to make it 1D or in my solution replace `a` with `[x[0] for x in a]`.

Comment: @Eyshika `a=[1]*10` if OK here but you have to be careful about it in general.

Comment: Ok I got it, but if I want to have 10,3 ones values so np.ones(10) will not work and np.ones(10,3) gives error then how will I use it there.

Comment: @Eyshika I just added an example that will handle `a=np.ones((10,3))`.

Comment: Thanx a lot! it works perfectly but again if x_1 y_1 are also 2d and i use it as np.vstack([np.asarray(a).T, np.asarray(x_1).T, np.asarray(y_1).T]).. then it doesn't work. It should work like x_1 is (3,2) y_1 is (3,2) and a is also (3,2) then after joining it should be (3,6) matrix. How will this work now.

Comment: @Eyshika _"I have updated my question for this."_ Instead of making this a rolling question with a moving target, consider opening new questions: I can't keep up with such permanently changing questions. Also about _"if `x_1` `y_1` are also 2d and i use it as `np.vstack([np.asarray(a).T, np.asarray(x_1).T, np.asarray(y_1).T])`.. then it doesn't work."_ You should not limit yourself to reading only about `vstack` but also look around for similar functions that serve slightly different purpose. For this particular situation `hstack` (without transposing arrays!) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

2D lists in python are different than in MATLAB!

If I have two lists

```
A = ["red", "green", "blue"]
B = ["orange", "yellow", "purple"]
```

And I wanted to create a 2D list out of these two, I could just write:

```
C = [A, B]
```

Then, C would be equal to [["red", "green", "blue"], ["orange", "yellow", "purple"]]

I could access elements of C such as:

```
C[0][1]
>> "red"
C[1][2]
>> "purple"
C[0]
>> ["red", "green", "blue"]
```

To answer your specific question, you have lists x_1 and y_1, and you want to create mat, a 2D list containing x_1 and y_1. You can just write,

```
mat = [x_1 y_1]
```

This list will be 2x10. You want to transpose this list, so you should be able to use zip to do:

```
mat = map(list, zip(*mat))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. i tried your method. It doesn't work.  When I am doing [x_1, y_1] it makes a list of length size =2 i.e. it is adding list as a another row or another list inside list, whereas I want to add in as in column wise.. with length of new list as 10.

Comment: Ah I see, so what you want is the same result but rotated? So this method gives you 2 by 10, but you want 10 by 2?

Comment: just updated the answer to include a list transpose at the end!

Comment: Works perfectly now.. Thanx!

Comment: I have one concern what if list is list of list then will this method work ? i.e. if a=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] and v= [[2,3,4],[2,3,4]] and I want it to convert as c=[[1,2,3,2,3,4],[1,2,3,2,3,4]] then will this work ?